# You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-01.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017/Testingdb?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=atlas-hrfqux-shard-0&ssl=true
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-16T11:30:24.198Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4333208, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM host selection timeout","attr":{"replicaSet":"atlas-hrfqux-shard-0","error":"FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"nearest\" } for set atlas-hrfqux-shard-0"}}


*** You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Error: connect failed to replica set atlas-hrfqux-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00.x2gaq.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

This error pops out everytime when I try to connect my mongo shell to the Mongodb Atlas.

Is there any solution to get rid out of this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Add your IP address to whitelist, and check the username and password are correct

Comment: My username and password I gave was correct and in the network access I allowed access from anywhere i.e. 0.0.0.0 . @Yahya

Comment: Just reset your username and password and try again

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same error and in my case it was my internet connection which was blocking the mongo servers. I switched from hostel LAN to normal wi-fi, and it got connected!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31473214)